# Jackson deserialize List<String> as a property of POJO

Tags: java, json, spring, collections, jackson

I have a POJO class which will be deserialized from JSON which comes as `RequestBody` in Spring. This POJO class contains `List<String>` as an instance variable. When this variable is deserialized, value is `null`. How to correctly deserialize it? Below are the code samples
My POJO looks like below

```
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BookDto {
@JsonProperty("bookName")
private String bookName;
@JsonProperty("authors")
private List<String> authors;
@JsonProperty("description")
private String description;
}
```

My JSON object looks like below

```
{
 "bookName":"Vagrant Up and Running",
 "authors":["aone", "atwo"],
 "description":"Getting started guide for Vagrant development"
}
```

Below is the sample method call

```
public void method(@RequestBody BookDto bookDto) {}
```

I had followed given suggestion and the deserializer code is given below

```
public class AuthorDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<List<String>> {
@Override
public List<String> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    Author author = jsonParser.readValueAs(Author.class);
    return author.authors;
}

private static class Author {
    public List<String> authors;
}
}
```

Comment: That can't possibly be your real code: all the fields are private, and there's no way to get their values. Post you actual code.

Comment: I have used lombok plugin for getters and constructors

Comment: Post your actual code.

Comment: @Madhusudhanan How are you deserializing it? Please post the code

Comment: I can't reproduce (although I don't use Lombok, but just generated the code it should generate based on annotations). Check your input. make sure you don't have a typo in there. Try to write a unit test which just deserializes the JSON.

Comment: @JBNizet Okay, I'll check. Thanks

Comment: @Madhusudhanan i couldnt reproduce your issue, as it works find even without your custom deserializer, please find my version on https://github.com/moband/spring-boot-lombok

Answer (score 0):

Make fields `Public` or add getter's to make them deserialize-able

Refer [this](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-field-serializable-deserializable-or-not) for more deails

Answer (score 0):

If you use Lombok, consider adding this annotation `@Data` like below:

```
@Data //You can remove the @Getter and @Setter annotation since @Data includes them
@NoArgsConstructor
public class BookDto {
   private String bookName;
   private List<String> authors;
   private String description;
}
```

Note: This is not related to the issue but please remove `@JsonProperty()`for clarity, this annotation is useless in your case since your JSON object's properties have the same name as your DTO's properties and by default the `ObjectMapper` use the names to map properties.

**EDIT:** `@RequestBody` deserializes the JSON for you so you don't need to do it manually.